# Default routing to index not work for new controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, .net-4.5

I have the following code for the navigation bar at the top of my application:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Users", "Index", "Account")</li>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Models", "Index", "Models")</li>
```

In AccountController I have the following Index function:

```
        [Authorize(Roles = "Admin, CanEditGroup, CanEditUser")]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var users = _db.Users;
            var model = new List<EditUserViewModel>();
            foreach (var user in users)
            {
                var u = new EditUserViewModel(user);
                model.Add(u);
            }
            return View(model);
        }
```

In ModelsController I have the following Index function:

```
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

When I click on the 'Users' link I am taken to '/Account' and the Index is correctly shown. However, when I click the 'Models' link I am taken to '/Models' and receive a 'HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden' error. When I debug this I can see that the Index function in 'ModelsController' isn't being hit. '/Models/Index' works fine though.

It should be noted that I am using a template where AccountController already existed. I have since added ModelsController.

Finally, here is my simple routing file:

```
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Please help me understand the difference between AccountController and ModelsController which is causing a difference in routing behaviour.

Comment: You could use a testing tool to verify the issue, something like: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx/.  I thought there was a newer tool, but can't find one...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i think you already have a models folder or some other resource with named models in your project.
you can change your controller name.

or set RouteExistingFiles for your route collections

```
routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
```

will help

Comment: Thanks marathonman, you've pointed me in the right direction. Since this is a MVC project, of course there is already a folder called 'Models'. 

I had hoped that the routing would be smart enough to know the difference between the MVC Models and my 'Models' controller/views. That doesn't appear to be the case though. Annoying as 'ModelsController' is the perfect description for what we're doing.

RouteExistingFiles actually worked but I've just renamed the controller and view folder as a better fix.

Comment: @Starky after my answer i also searched for something webforms's checkPhysicalUrlAccess . but i have no better answer at this time. i assume that reserved keywords for controller naming :)